# Border у <th> c помощью стиля

Tags: css

Как задать стиль, чтобы отображался border у th?
https://jsfiddle.net/dahilu/DBY7Z/14/

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>test</th>
    <td>test ahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjs</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>test</th>
    <td>test ahjshjdgjgssjgsjj</td>
</tr>
```

сss:

```
    table {
border:#ccc 1px solid;
border-collapse:separate;
border-spacing: 0;
width: 100%;
}

table tr td {
    border: 1px solid black;  
}

table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table {
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
table tr td,
table tr th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>test</th>
    <td>test ahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsj</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>test</th>
    <td>test ahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsjahjshjdgjgssjgsjgsjsgsjgjsgjsgsjsgsjsgsjgsj</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Вообще странное решение, обычно таблица выглядит так

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Заголовок</th>
        <th>Заголовок</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ячейка</td>
        <td>Ячейка</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Таблицу взял из чужого примера, не заметил даже такого решения.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).